# Updating the value of request header conditionally in nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I want to update the value of a request header conditionally so 
that the upstream sees the updated value instead of the originally 
sent one. To make the context clear, client may send a custom header 
say "Hdr-Token" whose value is set to "ABCD" in the HTTP Request and 
if this header is present, I want to update the value of the header 
to "EFGH". If the header itself is not present or the value is not 
"ABCD", I don't want to set/update i.e., I want to do it 
conditionally.

Tried with the following options:
1)Using content_by_lua_block

```
location  / {
        content_by_lua_block {
           if ngx.req.get_headers()["Hdr-Token"] == "ABCD" then
                   ngx.req.set_header("Hdr-Token", "EFGH");
           end
        }
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8101;
}
```

2)At the HTTP level added a map

```
map $http_hdr_token $is_ok {  
    default "0";  
    ABCD "1";  
}
```

and in the location block, added the following

```
location / {  
    if ($is_ok) {  
        proxy_set_header Hdr-Token 'EFGH';  
    }  
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8101;  
}
```

The first option did nothing and the second option threw an error saying, proxy_set_header can't be added there. I have added the nginx config below.

```
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE 
-fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security 
-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,
-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now'
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug 
--with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module 
--with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module 
--with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module  
--with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module 
--with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module
--with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module 
--with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream 
--with-stream_ssl_module --with-threads 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx-fancyindex 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-http-push 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-lua 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair 
--add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Can someone help me out here?  I thought, the module "/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-lua" should let me do what I am trying to do.
Please note that I don't have the liberty to compile nginx from source and can't install any package from ppa apart from the standard repo.